# Broken Ubuntu 18.10 Upgrade - libwine:i386

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

I have recently attempted to upgrade my system to Ubuntu 18.04 via:

> do-release-upgrade

The installation froze while attempting to install libwine:i386 as several hours had passed and the installer would not advance. I finally decided to cancel the release upgrade and execute the following:

> sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt-get -f install && sudo apt-get upgrade
>
> sudo dpkg --configure -a dpkg: dependency problems prevent
>   configuration of wine32:i386:  wine32:i386 depends on libwine (=
>   3.0-1ubuntu1); however:   Package libwine:i386 is not installed.
>
> dpkg: error processing package wine32:i386 (--configure):  dependency
>   problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent
>   configuration of widelands:  widelands depends on widelands-data (=
>   1:19+repack-4build4); however:   Version of widelands-data on system
>   is 1:19+repack-4.
>
> dpkg: error processing package widelands (--configure):  dependency
>   problems - leaving unconfigured Processing triggers for libc-bin
>   (2.27-3ubuntu1) ... dpkg: error processing package libwine:amd64
>   (--configure):  package libwine:amd64 cannot be configured because
>   libwine:i386 is not ready (current status 'half-installed') dpkg:
>   dependency problems prevent configuration of xorg:  xorg depends on
>   xserver-xorg (>= 1:7.7+19ubuntu7); however:   Version of xserver-xorg
>   on system is 1:7.7+19ubuntu3.
>
> dpkg: error processing package xorg (--configure):  dependency
>   problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent
>   configuration of wine64:  wine64 depends on libwine (= 3.0-1ubuntu1);
>   however:   Package libwine:amd64 is not configured yet.
>
> dpkg: error processing package wine64 (--configure):  dependency
>   problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent
>   configuration of wine-stable:  wine-stable depends on wine64 (>=
>   3.0-1ubuntu1) | wine32 (>= 3.0-1ubuntu1); however:   Package wine64 is not configured yet.   Package wine32:i386 is not configured yet. 
>   wine-stable depends on wine64 (<< 3.0-1ubuntu1.1~) | wine32 (<<
>   3.0-1ubuntu1.1~); however:   Package wine64 is not configured yet.   Package wine32:i386 is not configured yet.
>
> dpkg: error processing package wine-stable (--configure):  dependency
>   problems - leaving unconfigured Errors were encountered while
>   processing:  wine32:i386  widelands  libwine:amd64  xorg  wine64 
>   wine-stable

I then attempted:

> sudo apt --fix-broken install
>
> Reading package lists... Done Building
>   dependency tree        Reading state information... Done Correcting
>   dependencies... Done The following packages were automatically
>   installed and are no longer required:   bbswitch-dkms caribou
>   fonts-noto-color-emoji gcc-7-base:i386   gir1.2-caribou-1.0
>   gir1.2-clutter-1.0 gir1.2-cogl-1.0 gir1.2-coglpango-1.0
>   gir1.2-mutter-1 gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0 gir1.2-nmgtk-1.0
>   gnome-initial-setup gnome-todo gnome-todo-common gnome-tweak-tool
>   ibverbs-providers lib32gcc1 libapache2-mod-php7.2 libarmadillo7
>   libbabeltrace-ctf1 libbind9-140 libboost-atomic1.62.0
>   libboost-chrono1.62.0   libboost-chrono1.65-dev libboost-date-time-dev
>   libboost-date-time1.62.0   libboost-date-time1.65-dev
>   libboost-filesystem-dev   libboost-filesystem1.65-dev
>   libboost-iostreams1.62.0   libboost-program-options-dev
>   libboost-program-options1.65-dev   libboost-regex1.62.0
>   libboost-serialization1.62.0   libboost-serialization1.65-dev
>   libboost-system-dev libboost-system1.65-dev   libboost-test-dev
>   libboost-test1.62.0 libboost-test1.65-dev   libboost-test1.65.1
>   libboost1.65-dev libcamel-1.2-60 libcapnp-0.5.3   libcaribou-common
>   libcaribou0 libcdio-cdda1 libcdio-paranoia1 libcdio13   libcodec2-0.6
>   libcppunit-1.14-0 libcppunit-dev libcuda1-384 libdfu1   libdns162
>   libedataserver-1.2-22 libedataserverui-1.2-1 libfabric1
>   libfcitx-gclient0 libfreerdp-client2-2 libfreerdp2-2 libfwupd1
>   libgcr-3-common libgeos-3.5.1 libgl2ps1 libgl2ps1.4
>   libgnome-desktop-3-12   libgnome-games-support-1-2 libgnome-todo
>   libgnuradio-analog3.7.10   libgnuradio-atsc3.7.10
>   libgnuradio-channels3.7.10 libgnuradio-comedi3.7.10
>   libgnuradio-digital3.7.10 libgnuradio-dtv3.7.10 libgnuradio-fec3.7.10 
>   libgnuradio-fft3.7.10 libgnuradio-filter3.7.10 libgnuradio-noaa3.7.10 
>   libgnuradio-pager3.7.10 libgnuradio-qtgui3.7.10
>   libgnuradio-trellis3.7.10   libgnuradio-uhd3.7.10
>   libgnuradio-video-sdl3.7.10 libgnuradio-vocoder3.7.10
>   libgnuradio-wavelet3.7.10 libgnuradio-wxgui3.7.10
>   libgnuradio-zeromq3.7.10   libgom-1.0-common libgweather-3-6
>   libhamlib2 libhdf5-openmpi-100   libhwloc-plugins libhwloc5
>   libibverbs1 libical2 libicu57:i386 libidn11:i386   libisc160
>   libisccc140 libisccfg140 libisl15 libiso9660-10 libiso9660-8
>   liblept5 liblimesuite17.12-1 liblivemedia58 libllvm5.0:i386
>   liblog4cpp5-dev   liblouisutdml8 liblttng-ust-ctl2 liblwres141
>   libmpfr4 libmutter-1-0   libnetcdf-c++4 libnetcdf11 libnm-glib-vpn1
>   libntfs-3g872 libopencv-core3.1   libopencv-flann3.1
>   libopencv-imgproc3.1 libopencv-ml3.1 libopencv-photo3.1
>   libopencv-shape3.1 libopencv-video3.1 libopencv-viz3.1 libopenmpi2
>   liborcus-0.12-0 libp11-kit-gnome-keyring libpoppler68 libprocess-cpp3 
>   libpsm-infinipath1 libqcustomplot1.3 libqwt5-qt4 librdmacm1
>   librtaudio6   libsodium18 libsox2 libsrtp0 libssl1.0.0:i386
>   libsuitesparseconfig4   libsysmetrics1 libtbb2 libtesseract-data
>   libtesseract3 libu2f-udev   libunistring0 libunity-api0 libva-drm1
>   libva-wayland1 libva-x11-1   libvcdinfo0 libvlccore8 libvpx4 libvtk6.3
>   libwinpr2-2 libx264-148   libx265-130 libzmqpp4 nvidia-headless-390
>   nvidia-opencl-icd-384 openmpi-bin   openmpi-common python-qwt5-qt4
>   ruby2.3 snapd-login-service tcpd unixodbc   vlc-l10n vlc-plugin-notify
>   vlc-plugin-samba vlc-plugin-video-splitter Use 'sudo apt autoremove'
>   to remove them. The following additional packages will be installed:
>   libcapi20-3:i386 libwine:i386 widelands-data xserver-xorg Suggested
>   packages:   ttf-mscorefonts-installer:i386 The following NEW packages
>   will be installed:   libcapi20-3:i386 The following packages will be
>   upgraded:   libwine:i386 widelands-data xserver-xorg 3 upgraded, 1
>   newly installed, 0 to remove and 241 not upgraded. 7 not fully
>   installed or removed. Need to get 0 B/183 MB of archives. After this
>   operation, 9.108 kB of additional disk space will be used. Do you want
>   to continue? [Y/n] y (Reading database ... 380233 files and
>   directories currently installed.) Preparing to unpack
>   .../libwine_3.0-1ubuntu1_i386.deb ... Unpacking libwine:i386
>   (3.0-1ubuntu1) over (2.0.2-2ubuntu1) ...

Lastly I attempted to manually download libwine:i386.deb and install it via dpkg -i however the installer just freezes.

Does anyone know how I might be able to fix this?

Many thanks

Comment: First you converted your copy & paste text to `quote` format by clicking the `"` (open double quote button) instead of the `{}` (double brace button) for code blocks. Second you didn't say which version of Ubuntu you were upgrading from. Third are you sure you ran `sudo do-release-upgrade` and not `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`?

Answer (score 0):

very old post this may not help you now but this will help other guys:
to fix a broken update:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
```

if you have customized so many things in your them older version and you want to go back to default theme

```
dconf reset -f /
```